# Get the parameter from the url of site using asp with vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have the code of Jquery for link to the asp page as below:

Jquery code:

```
var url = "script_right2.asp?soc="+societe+"&phoneNum="+phoneNumber+"&seleDro="+sedro+"&desc="+des;
```

I want to get the value of `societe,phoneNumber,seleDro,desc` to the page `script_right2.asp`

But the problem is that I do not know how to get these data in asp page using vbscript.

Comment: you get the values of querystring in asp pages using `Request.QueryString("nameoffield")`. you can also use `Request("nameoffield")`. Is that what you were asking ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is so I'll answer it twice!

To replicate what you have using VBScript:

```
dim stringUrl
stringUrl = "script_right2.asp?soc=" & societe & "&phoneNum=" & phoneNumber & "&seleDro=" & sedro & "&desc=" & des;
```

---

Or, if you want to get the value of the variables from the query string you could do

```
dim soc
dim phone
dim sedro
dim desc

soc = Request.QueryString("soc")
phone = Request.QueryString("phoneNum")
sedro = Request.QueryString("seleDro")
desc = Request.QueryString("desc")
```